# What's better? Enum or Type checking?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, types

Suppose I want to parse some xml into a strongly-typed class. When I get the xml, I don't know if it should be type A or type B until I crack it open and take a look. I could take a look, and return an enum like this:

```
BaseType x = null;
TypeInfoEnum typeInfo = BaseType.GetTypeInfo(xml);

if(typeInfo == TypeInforEnum.TypeA)
{
    x = BaseType.ParseXmlToTypeA(xml);

    // do other work on Type A
}

else if(typeInfo == TypeInfoEnum.TypeB)
{
    x = BaseType.ParseXmlToTypeB(xml);

    // do other work on Type B
}
```

Or I could just handle the Parsing in one method and check the type:

```
BaseType x = BaseType.ParseXml(xml);

if(x.GetType() == typeof(TypeA))
{
    // do work on Type A
}
else if(x.GetType() == typeof(TypeB))
{
    // do work on Type B
}
```

Just wanting to get some others' thoughts from a design stand-point which you prefer. Right now, the details aren't very important. I'm just creating 2 different types from a single XML source, based on what's in the xml. Nothing complicated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answers so far. The types aren't really important here, but as an example, the class hierarchy might look like this:

```
class BaseType
{
    public string CommonData { get; set; }
}

class TypeA : BaseType
{
    public string TypeASpecificData { get; set; }
}

class TypeB : BaseType
{
    public string TypeBSpecificData { get; set; }
}
```

Since this functionality will be rolled into an assembly that others will use, I liked the first option using an Enum because it seems awkward to have users of an API check the type of something, i.e. using an Enum seems more semantically thorough.

Comment: Can you include an example of what TypeA and TypeB class might look like?

Comment: Just a typo i guess but still: 
 
if(typeInfo == TypeInforEnum.TypeA) one r too many

Comment: @Master117 too many what?

Comment: I would use the first way, always check before you parse to save time, also i think a switch would be quite nice here, but im still a bit confused how BaseType can have 2 different types like in the first example.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin TypeInforEnum should be TypeInfoEnum
r as the Letter not r as are for lazy people.

Comment: I prefer 1st snippet over 2nd which is not using any reflection, will be a little performance gain

Comment: I've done double-serialization where I have a wrapping `SerializedObject` which contains type information as strings (say its `Type.FullName` and assembly name), and a separate `Data` string property which contains the serialized XML for that type. Then you perform a second XML serialization on the `SerializedObject` instance. This way you can always deserialize type information, then a second deserialization after. I'm sure there are _better_ ways of doing this (especially to avoid double-serializing XML content, and to be less brittle, especially with more nested types) but it's simple.

Comment: Regarding your comment, I would rather see it via an interface: `if (myBaseTypeInstance is ITypeB) { }` or equivalent. At least that way if you have any reason to combine `TypeASpecificData` and `TypeBSpecificData` into a shared class you can do so. But perhaps this is a non-issue for you. I see no reason for it to be awkward for the caller to check the type of a deserialized type (though it might make more sense for the caller to _know_ before hand what they expect and leverage generics, but that may be outside the your design scope; which you can change if it makes more sense)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first option, you are essentially duplicating the information (type + enum) for no obvious benefit. Thus, given these two options, I'd choose the second one, although I'd prefer the more idiomatic `is` instead of the `GetType` comparison:

```
BaseType x = BaseType.ParseXml(xml);

if(x is TypeA)
{
    // do work on Type A
}
else if(x is TypeB)
{
    // do work on Type B
}
```

---

You might, however, consider a third option:

```
BaseType x = BaseType.ParseXml(xml);
x.DoWork();
```

with `DoWork` being an abstract method of BaseType which is overridden in TypeA and TypeB:

```
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public abstract void DoWork();
}
public class TypeA : BaseType
{
    public override void DoWork() {
        // do work on Type A
    }
}
public class TypeB : BaseType
{
    public override void DoWork() {
        // do work on Type B
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to be cautious of with the third option is whether DoWork makes sense as a responsibility of the TypeX instances.  In some cases, it might, but there are many cases where following this approach results in ongoing accretion of unrelated responsibilities to class hierarchies.

Comment: @DanBryant: Very good point. That's exactly the reason why I presented it as "another option" instead of "the ideal solution". I just lacked the words to describe why...

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to have 2 different methods - one that handles type A and another that handles type B:

```
public void DoWork(A a) { .. }

public void DoWork(B b) { .. }
```

And then you just send the instance to `doWork`. This will cause your code to do exactly what needs to be done without any type checks:

```
BaseType x = BaseType.ParseXml(xml);
DoWork(x);
```

Another option is to have the method DoWork implemented in both classes:

```
 public abstract class BaseType {
    public abstract void DoWork();
 }

 public class A: BaseType { 

    public void DoWork() { ... }
 }

 public class B: BaseType { 

    public void DoWork() { ... }
 }
```

And then your parsing would look like:

```
BaseType x = BaseType.ParseXml(xml);
x.DoWork();
```

Comment: The first example only works if you [cast x to `dynamic`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326386/using-dynamic-in-c-sharp-to-implement-visitor-pattern) first so that the compiler can generate the appropriate type comparisons and dynamic dispatch.  If you pass the base type directly, it will try to resolve the match at compile time and fail.

Comment: Nice catch. It depends on the way de-serialization happens. But basically, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

I commonly do like this:

1: Define some kind of key, for instance like you already suggest:

```
TypeInfoEnum typeInfo
{
...
}
```

2: Create a Dictionary with parsers declared like this:

```
Dictionary<TypeInfoEnum, Func<XDocument, IBase>>
```

3: Implement your public method like this:

```
public class Parser
{
    IBase Parse(XDocument xDocument)
    {
        TypeInfoEnum key = GetKeyForXDocument(xDocument);
        IBase x = DictionaryWithParsers[key](xDocument);

        return x;
    }
}
```

I ignored error handling and the implementation for the GetKeyForXDocument method, but that shouldn't be very difficult.

Your API consumer would consume it like this:

```
void SomeConsumingMethod()
{
    ...

    IBase x = serviceObject.Parse(xDocument);

    // Members declared in IBase:
    x.SomeMethod();

    // Members declared in ITypeA or ITypeB
    if (x is ITypeA)
        ((ITypeA)x).A();

    if (x is ITypeB)
        ((ITypeB)x).B();
}
```

Comment: I think that's a good solution for some scenarios, however in my specific usage, a user will only ever get a TypeA or TypeB, they can't extract both from the xml at will. The source of the xml is always the same, but what's contained within is either A or B.

Comment: Does the consumer know what type will be returned before calling your method?

Comment: No they wouldn't. They'll basically have to go down path A or path B depending on what's in the XML. Now, realistically, there's ~10 common fields between TypeA and TypeB, and about ~30 non-common fields for each, which is why I want them to be different objects in the first place. Basically, you open up the XML, and based on what's inside, you either go down the A path or the B path.

Comment: Then I would do it like I initially suggested. I've added some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would work, seems more straightforward.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TypeA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TypeB))]
class BaseType
{
    public string CommonData { get; set; }
}

class TypeA : BaseType
{
    public string TypeASpecificData { get; set; }
}

class TypeB : BaseType
{
    public string TypeBSpecificData { get; set; }
}
```

And to deserialize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseType));
BaseType result;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    result = (BaseType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Construction with Separation of Concerns**

I'm seeing violation of the single responsibility principle (SRP) because the parsing of the XML input is done w/in that class.

**Using enum Enables SRP Application**

... then the construction of classses A, B, C is decoupled from the classes themselves, or their base class. Do not define a base class for the sake of parsing that enum.

Given a valid `enum` value, pass that enum to a factory.

```
public static void main() {
    SomeClassFactory factory = new SomeClassFactory();

    // putting the parsing in the factory expresses the
    // association of the enum to its target types.
    SomeClassEnum someClassName = SomeClassFactory.Parse(xmlInput);
    BaseType someClassInstance = factory.Create(someClassName);
}

public class SomeClassFactory{
    // Potentially throws NotImplementedException
    public static SomeClassEnum Parse (string xmlInput) { ... }

    // the type is already resolved, so we don't need to do
    // it again in any of the code called herein.
    public SomeClassBase Create (SomeClassEnum thisClassName) {
        BaseType newInstance;

        switch(thisClassName) { 
            case SomeClassEnum.TypeA:
                newInstance = buildTypeA();
                break;
            // ...
        }

        return newInstance;
    }
}
```