# Efficient multiple type checks upon an incoming packet

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have an abstract `Packet`class to define the basic packet in my networking application. Once either the server or the client receives a packet, I only get the `Packet` object. I want to test for the type using `is` but it seems to me the casting is redundant when the `is` test succeeds. Using `as` would also work, but it requires one variable for each type I want to check. Isn't that inefficient? How can you test an object with many types in an efficient way? Here's an example:

```
public void HandlePacket(Packet packet)
{
    MessagePacket messagePacket = packet as MessagePacket;
    PingPacket pingPacket = packet as PingPacket;

    if (messagePacket != null)
    {
        //Handle message packet
    }
    else if (pingPacket != null)
    {
        //Handle ping packet
    }
    else if ...
}
```

Comment: I've used [dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326386/using-dynamic-in-c-sharp-to-implement-visitor-pattern) to get the above behavior without having to hard-code all of the checks/casts.  It has a higher overhead the first time the method is called, but once the dynamic implementation is compiled and cached, it should be close to the same performance as doing it manually, just with fewer variable names.

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, I should create a `dynamic castPacket` and check it with `if ((castPacket = packet as MessagePacket) != null)` ?

Comment: There's an example in the linked question; when you call a method with a dynamic parameter, it chooses the best (generally, most specific) overload from the set of methods with the same name.

Comment: you can use the `is` keyword. I tend to use an `byte Id` (Instead of byte you can use enum:byte)in the `Packet` class and then a simple `switch case` to call the appropriate handler

Comment: You didn't list any specs/requirements, so I may be off base with this comment. Efficient doesn't have to mean "the most possible efficient imaginable". Take a stab at it without too much worry of performance, and when you have something that works throw a profiler and some load at it. Keep yourself open to building efficiency where/when it's needed, not prematurely. Good design allows that to happen. As an example; you may find that the implementations of "handle" are consuming 99% of all the processor time and here you are spending an hour worrying about casting overhead where it's only 1%.

Comment: @Atoms sure, but I already have a working one using a dictionary. I don't think it's necessary slow, but I wanted to do it with casting to improve readability and performance at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)?

```
class Message {
  public abstract void Dispatch(MessageHandler handler); 
}

class PacketMessage: Message {
  override void Dispatch(MessageHandler handler) {
    handler.HandlePacket(this);
  }
}

class PingMessage: Message {
   override void Dispatch(MessageHandler handler) {
     handler.HandlePing(this);
   }
}


class MessageHandler {
  void HandleMessage(Message message) {
    message.Dispatch(this);   
  }

  void HandlePacket(PacketMessage packet) {
    ...
  }

  void HandlePing(PingMessage ping) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Oooooo that's a nice concept. Going to have to bookmark that wiki page. Fingers crossed I remember this when I need it :D

Comment: @TyCobb [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8) should be on your desk :)

Comment: Ordered!  *Seriously, putting in the order now.*

Comment: Thank you, this is a really elegant way. @TyCobb I think I might want this book haha

Answer (score 2):

I would go the route of `is` and specifically have methods in place for handling specific `Packet` types.

```
public void HandlePacket(Packet packet)
{   
    if (packet is MessagePacket)
    {
        HandleMessagingPacket((MessagePacket)packet);
    }
    else if (pingPacket is PingPacket)
    {
        HandlePingPacket((PingPacket)packet);
    }
    else if ...
}
```

There isn't much you can do aside from `dynamic` as mentioned in the comments. I prefer this route due separating logic between types and not even needing a variable other than `packet`.

Another option would be to set up a `Dictionary<Type, Action>` and build your handlers in there first. The only *gotcha* is the fact you now have to double check you got the correct packet type in the handler.

```
public class MyPacketHandler
{
    Dictionary<Type, Action<Packet>> _packetHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Packet>>();
    public MyPacketHandler()
    {
        _packetHandlers.Add(typeof(MessagePacket), HandleMessagePacket);
        _packetHandlers.Add(typeof(PingPacket), HandlePingPacket);
    }

    public void HandlePacket(Packet packet)
    {
        var type = packet.GetType();
        if(!_packetHandlers.Contains(type))
            throw new NotSupportedException(type.Name + " is not supported");

        _packetHandlers[type].Invoke(packet);
    }

    public void HandleMessagePacket(Packet packet)
    {
        var messagePacket = packet as MessagePacket;
        if(packet == null)
            throw new Exception("oops");
    }
}
```

*Note: The above is fully untested...*

Comment: The Dictionary approach is especially nice if you want to support adding new handlers at run-time.  This can be useful for designs with 'plugins' as one possible extensibility point.  It does add some overhead, though.

Comment: Yes I though of using a dictionary but thought the type comparison was actually a lot more expensive than a simple cast. I might be wrong, but I need maximum performance here.

Answer (score 0):

An extensible approach to consider (largely simplified/condensed, can be taken further/improved where needed). No efficiency claims.

```
public interface IPacket
{
  string PacketType { get; }
  object Payload { get; }
}

public interface IPacketHandler
{
  string PacketType { get; }
  void Handle(IPacket packet);
}

public class MessagePacket : IPacket, IPacketHandler
{
  public string PacketType { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
  public object Payload { get; private set; }
  public void Handle(IPacket packet)
  { 
    // ...
  }
}

public class PingPacket : IPacket, IPacketHandler
{
  public string PacketType { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
  public object Payload { get; private set; }
  public void Handle(IPacket packet)
  {
    // ... 
  }
}

public class PacketReceiver
{
  private readonly Dictionary<string, IPacketHandler> packetHandlerLookup;

  // inject handlers using favored approach...
  public PacketReceiver(IPacketHandler[] handlerReferences)
  {
    this.packetHandlerLookup = handlerReferences
      .ToDictionary(h => h.PacketType);
  }

  public void Receive(IPacket packet)
  {
    IPacketHandler handler;
    this.packetHandlerLookup.TryGetValue(packet.PacketType, out handler);

    if (handler == null)
    {
      throw new Exception(string.Format(
        "Unknown packet handler for {0}",
        packet.PacketType));
    }

    handler.Handle(packet);
  }
}
```